# Construction @User.IsInRole("admin") return only false

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, roles

I have got a short question: recently I have created a web application in ASP.NET Core 3.1, where I have been using Identity framework to authorize/autenthize of an user.
In navigation part of page I would like to display a role of user, so I wrote following code snippet in partial view:

@if (User.IsInRole("admin") {...}

But there is a problem, mentioned construction permanently returns "false".

Any idea to fix this error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean your the result is always false?

Comment: Yes, result of if(...) is always false.

Comment: I suggest you could try to create a api to get all user claims `public IActionResult Index()
{
    var claims = User.Claims.Select(claim => new { claim.Type, claim.Value }).ToArray();
    return Json(claims);
}`. Then you could check the user's role claims value is admin or not. I guess the user's role is not admin.